# Why does LAG return null for all but one row?

Tags: sql, oracle

I’m attempting to fetch rows that are ranked second in a group, along with a value from the previous (first-ranked) row using `LAG`.

However, applying the condition `where place = 2` causes the result set to only have a `LAG` result for the first row.

Including a `LEAD` column causes the expected result to be shown in the `LAG` column.

I’m using Oracle 19c and the table I’m working with looks like this:

```
UKNUM PARTY   UKVOTES
----- ------ --------
    1 con        6605
    1 lab       23745
    1 lib        8206
    1 plaid      1859
```

There are at least three rows for each `uknum`, and all of the columns are non-null.

This is my query, intended to fetch the second-placed rows (by `ukvotes`) with the `ukvotes` value for the first-placed rows:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      uknum,
      rank() OVER (PARTITION BY uknum ORDER BY ukvotes DESC) AS place,
      lag(ukvotes) OVER (PARTITION BY uknum ORDER BY ukvotes DESC) AS lag
    FROM
      ukresults
  )
WHERE
  place = 2
  AND uknum BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

This yields the following results:

```
     UKNUM      PLACE        LAG
---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2      23745
         2          2
         3          2
         4          2
         5          2
```

I would expect that for rows 2-5 there would be a non-null value in the `LAG` column.

Adding `LEAD` to the query causes the `LAG` column to contain the expected results:

```sql
SELECT
  *
FROM
  (
    SELECT
      uknum,
      rank() OVER (PARTITION BY uknum ORDER BY ukvotes DESC) AS place,
      lag(ukvotes) OVER (PARTITION BY uknum ORDER BY ukvotes DESC) AS lag,
      lead(ukvotes) OVER (PARTITION BY uknum ORDER BY ukvotes DESC) AS lead
    FROM
      ukresults
  )
WHERE
  place = 2
  AND uknum BETWEEN 1 AND 5;
```

```
     UKNUM      PLACE        LAG       LEAD
---------- ---------- ---------- ----------
         1          2      23745       6605
         2          2      19262       7426
         3          2      15393      10372
         4          2      31288       6070
         5          2      24148      11599
```

I’m confused as to why the first query does not produce the expected results, with a `LAG` value for all of the rows.

[Here’s a DBFiddle with the data and the queries loaded.](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=b30e800c9978dc0375e5d3dd7b46d565)

Update: here are the query plans from Oracle 19c, first for the query using `LAG` only, then one for `LEAD` by itself or `LAG` and `LEAD` together (plan is the same for either query containing `LEAD`).

`LAG` only plan:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation                | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT         |           |   197 |  7683 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                    |           |   197 |  7683 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|*  2 |   WINDOW SORT PUSHED RANK|           |   197 |  1773 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER  | UKRESULTS |   197 |  1773 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN     | UKNUMX    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("PLACE"=2)
   2 - filter(RANK() OVER ( PARTITION BY "UKNUM" ORDER BY
              INTERNAL_FUNCTION("UKVOTES") DESC )<=2)
   4 - access("UKNUM"<=50)
```

`LEAD` only / `LAG` and `LEAD` plan:

```
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Id  | Operation              | Name      | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT       |           |   197 |  7683 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|*  1 |  VIEW                  |           |   197 |  7683 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   2 |   WINDOW SORT          |           |   197 |  1773 |     5  (20)| 00:00:01 |
|   3 |    TABLE ACCESS CLUSTER| UKRESULTS |   197 |  1773 |     4   (0)| 00:00:01 |
|*  4 |     INDEX RANGE SCAN   | UKNUMX    |     1 |       |     2   (0)| 00:00:01 |
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):
---------------------------------------------------

   1 - filter("PLACE"=2)
   4 - access("UKNUM"<=50)
```

Comment: Show the number of votes for each row.  The original data would also help.  You can set up a db<>fiddle of some sort.

Comment: Your query does not seem to yield the results you led us to expect but perhaps I don't have the data right. [See this dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=385f58cff352d9010cd49a802ab0b814)

Comment: DBFiddle available here: https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=26c22fe65c7151e6a41400fe35aa0109
@BobJarvis it provides a result for the first row only, but null for the rest.

Comment: Ah, very good - thanks for the dbfiddle. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like a bug in optimizer.

As if it pushed the `WHERE place = 2` filter to the main query after evaluating `RANK`, but before evaluating `LAG`. But, only after the first row.

It produces even weirder results with `WHERE place = 1`.

If I change the Oracle version to 11g in the dbfiddle, it produces expected results.

Maybe, it is a bug in dbfiddble?

Comment: If so, I think it may be an issue with Oracle itself. The original results were from my university’s Oracle 19c instance.

Comment: Pushing `rank()` a level deeper (by having it in a subquery from which the `lag`-using subquery draws works around this problem. It appears that the where clause needs to be separated from `rank()` by two levels (ie in the outer query here).

Answer (score 0):

This is quite confusing.  `lag()` is really a lad because the ordering is descending.

My best guess is that `uknum`s 2-5 do not have a 3rd place finisher.

Comment: `lag() is really a lad` ... quote of the day :-)

Comment: There are at least three rows for each `uknum`.